# Hover effect on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to animate a pop-up only after the mouse has been over the link for a specific amount of time. Please help. Using Jquery.????

Comment: In this site i try 2 use "HoverIntent" buti dint get work on it. http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html"

Comment: I don't understand - is that your work? If so, it already does what you want it to. If not, then please show us what you've written so far.

Comment: What @no.good.at.coding is getting at is that we can't help you unless you show us what you've tried already. For instance, amending your question to include some portion of your source code is really useful, as are complete sentences.

Comment: Below the code i used in my site:



function popup1(e){

 var id = e.id;
 setTimeout("delayedPopup('"+id+"')",1000);
 return false;      
}






<!--Html-->
 <div id="4"   onMouseOut="popup_close(this)" onMouseOver="popup1(this)"><a href="#" >Link</a></div>

Answer (score 1):

```
//Here is my trial
//create a global var called canShow that will be set to true 
//as the mouse is over the cursor, and then reset when the mouse moves away. 
//then use timeout to display the popup after some interval 
//as long as the canShow hasn't been reset to false.

var canShow = false;
var desiredTimeOut = 2000; //in milliseconds
var intervalId;

//assume our link has id 'linkId'
//we'll use jquery since you tag with it
$('#linkId').hover(function(){
  canShow = true;
  intervalId = setTimeout(function() {
    if(canShow == true) $('#myPopupId').show();
  }, desiredTimeOut);

}).mouseout(function() { canShow = false; clearInterval(intervalId);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, is suppose, you could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/mazzzzz/TJvSC/